# Align rows to match column

Tags: database, vba, excel

**Problem**

How can you horizontally align values in separate columns, and apply a dynamic formula? Preemptive thank you for any help or clues! The code pasted below works, in so far as it reaches halfway to the end destination. But how to accomplish the last two objectives?

1) Sum each range

2) Align the ranges horizontally

A sample sheet containing customer id, item and prices. Sales from Monday on the left, Tuesday on the right.

[image: Before align and sum]

**Current results**
[image: Semi aligned, no sum]

**Desired results**

Align cust id on rows A and E, with an associated sum. *Notice how each yellow line contains cust id for identification, as well as associated Sum total.*
[image: Align and sum]

**Existing VBA Code**

```
Sub AlignAndMatch()
    'backup sheet
    ActiveSheet.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'Insert rows where current cell <> cell above
    Dim i, totalrows As Integer
    Dim strRange As String
    Dim strRange2 As String

    '----------------------------------------
    'Monday sort table
    Range("A2:C65536").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A2:C65536"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    'Monday insert loop
    totalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    i = 0

    Do While i <= totalrows
       i = i + 1
       strRange = "A" & i
       strRange2 = "A" & i + 1
       If Range(strRange).Text <> Range(strRange2).Text Then
           Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 2, 3)).Insert xlDown 'think cells ~A1:C2 insert
           totalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
           i = i + 2 'for insert 2 rows
       End If
    Loop

    'Monday footer row loop
    totalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
    i = 0

    Do While i <= totalrows
       i = i + 1
       If IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i + 1).Value) Then
           Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i + 1).Value
           Range("B" & i).Value = "Sum"
       End If
    Loop

    '----------------------------------------
    'Tuesday sort table
    Range("E2:G65536").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("E2:G65536"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    'Tuesday insert loop
    totalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
    i = 0

    Do While i <= totalrows
       i = i + 1
       strRange = "E" & i
       strRange2 = "E" & i + 1
       If Range(strRange).Text <> Range(strRange2).Text Then
           Range(Cells(i + 1, 5), Cells(i + 2, 7)).Insert xlDown 'think cells ~A1:C2 insert
           totalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
           i = i + 2 'for insert 2 rows
       End If
    Loop

    'Tuesday footer row loop
    totalrows = ActiveSheet.Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).Row
    i = 0

    Do While i <= totalrows
       i = i + 1
       If IsEmpty(Range("E" & i).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Range("E" & i + 1).Value) Then
           Range("E" & i).Value = Range("E" & i + 1).Value
           Range("F" & i).Value = "Sum"
       End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Are you just looking for a dynamic "SUM" formula that sums the values below, until the first empty row?

Comment: The current code works flawlessly, but I just did the easy part. The hard part is aligning the rows so that all 'cust id' values align between the two tables, as well as this sum. I'm working to implement dynamic SUM, per @BruceWayne idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I needed something like that I might think twice what I want and why: if the original day lists don't come from somehwere, you could put everything into one list and make some pivots...

But. Here's some idea, playing with the arrays again and there's probably work to do, but does this help:

```
Option Base 1

Sub ReLists()

Dim ListSheet As Worksheet
Dim DayCorners() As Range
Dim Day()
Dim Days As Integer
Dim CustIDs()
Dim CustomerRow()           'for placement in the final list
Dim DayList()
Dim MaxCustIDs As Integer
Dim NewCustID As Boolean

Days = 2
MaxCustIDs = 5

ReDim DayCorners(Days)
ReDim Day(Days)
ReDim CustomerRow(MaxCustIDs + 2)
CustomerRow(1) = 0

ReDim CustIDs(MaxCustIDs)
ReDim DayItems(1, 1)

Set ListSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set DayCorners(1) = ListSheet.Range("A2")
Set DayCorners(2) = ListSheet.Range("E2")

For d = 1 To Days

    With ListSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=DayCorners(d)
        .SetRange Range(DayCorners(d), DayCorners(d).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2))
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With

    Day(d) = Range(DayCorners(d), DayCorners(d).End(xlDown).Offset(0, 2))

    If UBound(Day(d), 1) > UBound(DayItems, 2) Then
        ReDim DayItems(Days, UBound(Day(d)))
    End If

Next d

CustIDCount = 0

For d = 1 To Days

    For r = 1 To UBound(Day(d), 1)

    NewCustID = True

        For u = 1 To UBound(CustIDs)
            If CustIDs(u) = Day(d)(r, 1) Then NewCustID = False
        Next u
        If NewCustID Then
            CustIDCount = CustIDCount + 1
            CustIDs(CustIDCount) = Day(d)(r, 1)

        End If
    Next r

Next d

    With Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(ListSheet.Index))
        Set DayCorners(1) = .Range("A2")
        Set DayCorners(2) = .Range("E2")
    End With

ReDim DayList(Days, CustIDCount, 100, 3)

For d = 1 To Days

    For c = 1 To CustIDCount

    rc = 1

            For r = 1 To UBound(Day(d), 1)

                If Day(d)(r, 1) = CustIDs(c) Then

                    DayList(d, c, rc, 1) = Day(d)(r, 1)
                    DayList(d, c, rc, 2) = Day(d)(r, 2)
                    DayList(d, c, rc, 3) = Day(d)(r, 3)

                    rc = rc + 1

                End If

            Next r

        If CustomerRow(c) + rc + 2 > CustomerRow(c + 1) Then

            CustomerRow(c + 1) = CustomerRow(c) + rc + 1

        End If

    Next c

    If CustomerRow(c - 1) + rc + 2 > CustomerRow(c) Then

            CustomerRow(c) = CustomerRow(c) + rc

    End If

Next d

For d = 1 To Days

With DayCorners(d).Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:C1")
    .Value = Array("cust id", "item", "Price")
    'formatting
End With

    For c = 1 To CustIDCount

    SumFormula = "=SUM(R[1]C:R[" & (CustomerRow(c + 1) - CustomerRow(c) - 1) & "]C)"

    With DayCorners(d).Offset(CustomerRow(c), 0).Range("A1:D1")
        If Not IsEmpty(DayList(d, c, 1, 1)) Then
            .Value = Array(CustIDs(c), "Sum", SumFormula, "")
        End If
        .Interior.Color = 65535
    End With

            For rc = 1 To UBound(Day(d), 1)

                If IsEmpty(DayList(d, c, rc, 1)) Then Exit For

                DayCorners(d).Offset(CustomerRow(c) + rc, 0) = DayList(d, c, rc, 1)
                DayCorners(d).Offset(CustomerRow(c) + rc, 1) = DayList(d, c, rc, 2)
                DayCorners(d).Offset(CustomerRow(c) + rc, 2) = DayList(d, c, rc, 3)

            Next rc

    Next c

Next d

End Sub
```